# Читай или считай в скобках?

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте, существуют ли какие-то нормы в употреблении уточняющих слов в скобках, пример:
"Испанское издание Super Deporte (**считай:** Mirror) сообщает,что...."
Правильно ли писать **"считай"**, ведь речь идет о прочтении, устоявшаяся ли это норма? Я всегда думал, что правильно будет **"читай"** в таких случаях.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что дубликат http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424440

Comment: Дубликат http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424440