# "Читай" или "считай" в скобках? Существуют ли правила?

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте, существуют ли какие-то нормы в употреблении уточняющих слов в скобках, например:

"Испанское издание Super Deporte (**считай:** Mirror) сообщает, что..."

Правильно ли писать **"считай"**, ведь речь идет о прочтении, устоявшаяся ли это норма? Я всегда думал, что правильно будет **"читай"** в таких случаях.

Comment: А в чем сомнение? Если речь идет о прочтении, правильно: "читай" Не совсем понятно, зачем нужно здесь писать "считай".

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так и этак. "Читай" - более употребительная форма, но она ограничена употреблением, возможно только когда речь идет именно о различных прочтениях.

У вас же, судя по всему, речь идет об испанском издании, которое каким-то образом связано с более известным "Mirror". Не знаю деталей, то ли дочерняя структура, то ли новости оттуда переписывает... В любом случае "считай" будет более правильно, поскольку "прочитать" Super Deporte как Mirror невозможно (*да и двусмысленно будет звучать "Читай Mirror" - как предложение читать эту самую "Миррор"*), а вот **считать**, что новость сообщила именно Mirror, - в таком случае вполне понятно и адекватно ситуации.

Так что я считаю, что написано правильно, по крайней мере если автор имел в виду именно это.

Без контекста подробнее не могу.

(+)

> Контекст, что "Mirror" это желтая газетенка, соответственно и "Super
>   Deport" тоже. Я таки как раз думаю, что надо писать в скобках "читай".
>   Видишь Депор Спор, а читай Миррор. Как вы думаете, уместно ли здесь
>   писать считай"?

В Вашем прочтении здесь неуместно ни то, ни другое. Потому, что это наклеивание ярлыков.

Нашел.

> Ввиду сложившейся ситуации уместно полагать, что решение этой проблемы
>   может находиться в составе. Моуринью может положиться на игроков в его
>   распоряжении. Однако слухи связывают Андре Гомеша из «Валенсии» с
>   переходом в «Юнайтед». Испанское издание Super Deporte (считай,
>   Mirror) сообщает, что клуб подтвердит его трансфер этим летом.

http://carrick.ru/texts/where-man-united-need-to-strengthen-their-squad-this-summer/

Нет, здесь никаких экивоков насчет желтизны я не усматриваю. Это надо у автора спрашивать, почему я должен считать "Super Deporte" "Мirror'oм".

Правда, "читать" одно как другое я совсем не пониаю. Так что скорее всего тут именно "считать", но мотивы автора мне непонятны. "Мirror" (если речь идет о "Дэйли Миррор") даже не спортивное издание.

(++)

**А, вон оно чего!!!** Все ясно.

Не поленился найти все первоисточники. В английском оригинале стоит "h/t Mirror".

http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2643618-breaking-down-where-manchester-united-need-to-strengthen-their-squad-this-summer

H/T (Hat Tip - приподнимаю шляпу) - указание на источник  предоставленной информации, обычно - благодарность. И действительно, первой эту инфу опубликовала Mirror.

В таком раскладе и "считай" и "читай" - не лучший выбор. Правда, если "читай" ошибочно по смыслу, то "считай" - просто не совсем корректно по этикету, что, конечно, ошибка куда меньшая.

На мой вкус, должно быть что-то типа ***"DP (по данным Mirror)" или "(благодаря Mirror)"***  - ну тут надо уже смотреть, что там по стилистике больше подходит, переводить всю статью мне лениво.

А вы говорите "контекста нет" )))). Да тут все дело в нём.

Comment: Контекст, что "Mirror" это желтая газетенка, соответственно и "Super Deport" тоже. Я таки как раз думаю, что надо писать в скобках "читай". Видишь Депор Спор, а читай Миррор. Как вы думаете, уместно ли здесь писать считай"?

Comment: @Роман64 это только ваш взгляд на контекст - да и совсем не на то, что здесь важно. Вы текст приведите, хотя бы несколько фоаз - и смысл остального. Или ссылку.  Важно понять, по какому поводу вообще вспомнили одно издание - и вдруг  переключились на другое. Если только для того, чтобы оскорбить, то это называется "наклеить ярлык". Здесь нет ни фактического, ни даже сравнительного материала, чтобы писать в скобках подобные аналогии. Ни "читай", ни "считай".

Comment: Да особого контекста нет, это перевод одного блоггера на футбольную тему. Конкретно в этой статье обсуждаются трансферные слухи, что и характеризует эти газеты, как не самые авторитетные в плане достоверности информации. В англ варианте в скобках было так: ("h\t Mirror) - (хештег Миррор). Те. допустим, что ваши "Известия", что ваша "Сельская Жизнь" пишут о проблемах села,

Comment: Нашел уже. см. текст ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваше разъяснение по поводу двусмысленности действительно полезно.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, вы позволите, если я заскриню или скопирую ваш ответ про H\T и выложу там?

Comment: @Роман64 Конечно, можно. Можно было и не спрашивать, а если спрашивать, то не у меня а у ресурса. Но здесь только приветствуется. Желательно только ссылку на источник давать http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424440 - такую.